# How do I hide a section when I show a different section?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically I want one section to be shown at first as the home page. When I click on a link, I want that section to be shown, but everything else hidden, and so on. Every time I click a link, I only want the clicked on link's section to be shown.

I am close, but stuck. Here is my HTML:

```
<a href="#about" id="about" class="text-center" title="">About Me</a>                   
<a href="#contact" id="contact" class="text-center" title="">Contact</a>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container about showing">
        <h2>About Me</h2>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container about showing">
        <h2>Contact</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.about').hide();
$('.contact').hide();

$('.showing').show();

$('#contact').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('div').removeClass('showing');
    $('.contact').addClass('showing');
    if ($('div').hasClass('showing')) {
        $('div').show();
    } else {
        $('div').hide();
    }
});

});
```

So it shows the 'About Me' section right away and everything else is hidden. When I click the 'Contact' link it removes the 'showing' class from all my 'div's and adds the 'showing' class to my contact section. I then check to see if the 'div' has the 'showing' class, if it does I have it show the 'div' otherwise I want it to hide it.

However, when I click on the Contact link, it does show the Contact section, but it does not hide the About Me section. I know this is a long post, I am just trying to make sure I explain everything correctly. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would highly encourage to make this generic so you don't have to duplicate logic or bindings.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest you use data fields and common classes to make it generic.

```js
var $pages = $('.container');

$('.menu').on('click', function(e){
  //remove showing from all containers
  $pages.removeClass('showing');
  //put it on the container with the matching class of the data target
  $pages.filter('.'+ $(e.target).data('target')).addClass('showing');
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: none;
}

.container.showing {
  display: unset;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#about" class="menu text-center" data-target="about" title="">About Me</a>
<a href="#contact" class="menu text-center" data-target="contact" title="">Contact</a>
<a href="#other" class="menu text-center" data-target="other" title="">Other</a>


<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="container home showing">
    <h2>Home</h2>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="container about">
    <h2>About Me</h2>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="container contact">
    <h2>Contact</h2>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="container other">
    <h2>Other</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few things you can optimize:

```js
       $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.about, .contact').hide(); //put both of them in single selector
        $('.showing').show(); //this shows the only element that has "showing
    
        $('#contact, #about').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
    
            var self = $(this); //reference to the object being clicked
            var target = $("." + self.attr('id'));
    
            //removes "showing" class from all others and hides them
            $(".container").not(target).removeClass("showing").hide();
    
            //adds "showing" class to the new current item
            target.addClass("showing").show();
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#about" id="about" class="text-center" title="">About Me</a>                   
    <a href="#contact" id="contact" class="text-center" title="">Contact</a>
    
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container about showing">
            <h2>About Me</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container contact"> <!--you don't want that "showing" class here!-->
            <h2>Contact</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I tried this code out, but when I click on the Contact link it just removes all my containers and doesn't show anything.

Comment: @BrandonLearnsAlot sorry, I missed the point of what's being clicked and what needs to be hiddden. Converted my answer to a code snippet which works now. Also, note that I changed some of the HTML elements' classes.